# Any idea as to why my Ionic/Angular PWA is showing the white screen of death?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

https://app.certivision.co.uk

I've been drilling my head against the wall for a couple of evenings in a row now and I'm not sure as to why my angular/ionic pwa app is showing the white screen of death. From what I can see there are no console errors/network errors. How do I go about getting this working? It works locally when using https-server -o and ionic serve.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks and best regards!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Does this happen on all platforms or just on iOS? There have been reports of the white screen of death when an update to a  PWA is deployed. It is a difficult business to debug, because it is not easy to reproduce the conditions and as you say there are no errors anywhere.

We came across this problem and I'm trying to gather some information so that it can be reported or at least made public. This pretty much kills the PWA on iOS for us, because the only way to recover from this is to clear all browser data - which you cannot require the user to do.

Answer (score 3):

You have **opacity: 0;** in your one of your css file. It might be at your app-component.css please check it. Also you can search **opacity: 0;** in your project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXzQF.jpg

Comment: I've already checked for the obvious - searched the entire project folder in vscode. Do you think it could be the ionic splash screen doing something funny ? I tried to remove it and not sure if I've removed properly. So I think maybe the splashscreen is causing the opacity issue ?

Comment: If you can share some of your code I can check for what's happening there. Problem can be at splash screen or it can be one of your [hidden] = "condition" etc. Its so hard to guess like that.